# Master Theorem extendet case

Tags: algorithm, iteration, time-complexity, duration

Can someone explain this to me ?

I have this case:

**T(n) = 3*T(n/3) + n*logn**

Why is this case the Master Theorem case two and not three ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, according to the [wikipedia notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem):

```
a = 3
b = 3
c = log_b(a) = 1
```

This fits case 2: `f(n) = n log n = n^(c = log_b(a) = 1) log n`

It does not fit case 3, because `f(n)` is not `big-omega(n^k)`, where `k > c = 1` (I changed the wikipedia notation a little so as not to redefine `c`).

It might not be immediately obvious that `n^1.1` is not a lower bound for `n log n` for example, but `n^1.1` [is actually a bigger value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20n%5E1.1%20%2F%20%28n*log%28n%29%29%20as%20n%20approaches%20infinity) for large enough `n`.

Comment: was it your intention to save this as wikipedia notation ?http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3029376/Russian-volunteer-head-transplant-operation-Valery-Spiridonov-says-no-choice-undergo-7-5million-procedure-controversial-Italian-surgeon-Dr-Sergio-Canavero.html

Comment: I was hoping no one would catch that :) it's fixed now, sorry!

Comment: No Problem =) But in Case 2 is it: c = log_b(a) and in the example c = nlogn and log_b(a) = 1 and nlogn > log_b(a) or did i missunderstood something

Comment: Not sure I follow. When is `c = n log n`? `c = log base b of a = 1` always for your  problem.

Comment: I read that c follows from f(n) and in my example **f(n) = nlogn ,  a = 3 and b=3** so that c >log_b(a), I think my problem is i don´t now how i should handle the **nlogn** in each other case it is **n² where c = 2**